# Launch DetailViewController from Map Annotation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm missing something to do with the navigation controllers to make this happen.

I don't get an error, but, my view controller after the annotation is clicked doesn't go.

Here's the code that I'm trying to use:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [view annotation];
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CACPlacemark class]]) {
        CACPlacemark *tappedSite = (CACPlacemark *)[view annotation];
        NSNumber *MyUID = [tappedSite UID];
        NSString *LocalTitle = [annotation title];
        NSLog(@"%@",LocalTitle);
        NSLog(@"%@",MyUID);
        int mapX = [MyUID intValue];
        CACDetailMapViewController *vc = [[CACDetailMapViewController alloc] init];
        vc.uniqueId = mapX;
        vc.delegate = self;
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

One thing that I might be missing here is that my main controller is a "tab bar controller", pointing to a "Navigation Controller".

I think this is where my problem is on why it doesn't go, but, I'm really stuck.

Comment: Please log self.parrentViewController

Comment: Is self.navigationController non-nil? Also, alloc init might not be the correct way to instantiate your controller depending on where you made it.

Comment: Sviatoslav Yakymiv, If I try to use "[[self parentViewController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];" or [self.parentViewController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];" I get an error that "no visible @interface for UIViewController declares pushViewController". rdelmar, I tried to interrogate that, but I believe it to be 'nil, and that's where I don't understand what I need to do. Unfortunately, in the examples I've seen, I haven't seen any explanation of that and I think that is my problem.

Comment: I created the view controller on the storyboard.